# Call rich:modalPanel for every ajax request with out using a4j:status?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I am developing web application using JSF richfaces.I have one **rich:modalpanel** in main templete. This modalPanel have 'Your request is processing....." message.

I want to show this message(*modalPanel*) every action(*ajax request*). But without using **a4j:status** element.

Is there possible to acheive this(using **listener** or any otherway)?
How to show the wait modalPanel for all action using **listener**?

Help me about this.
Thanks in advance.

**Update :**

If i use my main templete,

```
<a4j:status id="waittingMessage"
            onstart="javascript:Richfaces.showModalPanel('progressWaitModalPanel');"
            onstop="javascript:Richfaces.hideModalPanel('progressWaitModalPanel');"/>
```

And i call the above **a4j:status** for the following places :
The following each and every component i use more than 100 place in my application

```
            <a4j:commandButton status="waittingMessage"/> 
            <a4j:commandLink   status="waittingMessage"/> 
<h:selectOneMenu><a4j:support  status="waittingMessage"/>  </h:selectOneMenu>
<h:selectOneRadio><a4j:support status="waittingmessage"/></h:selectOneRadio>
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox><a4j:support status="waittingmessage"/></h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

In future,

i don't need to show the **progressWaitModalPanel**, that time i will delete **a4j:status**
in main templete.
But what about this **status="waittingMessage"**? Because this **status="waittingmessage"** i added more than 1000 places in my whole application.

Answer (score 1):

`<a4j:status>` is the proper way to do this. I don't know of any other way. Perhaps you can hook to some low-level javascript, but that would be the wrong thing to do.

If the `status` is in the current `form`, there is no need to explicitly indicate which is the status - it is used by default.

Comment: thanks for your reply. 
Is possible to use listener for accomplished this process.

Comment: I don't think so. What listeners, you mean?

Comment: PhaseListener,ActionListener,HttpSessionListener and something

Comment: even if that was possible, it would be ugly. Why exactly you don't want `<a4j:status>` ?

Comment: I agree with Bozho. It's best to use a4j:status. Some custom JavaScript could be used but really not the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a4j:status id="waittingMessage"
        onstart="Richfaces.showModalPanel('id_modalPanel')"
        onstop="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('id_modalPanel')">
        <f:facet name="start">
            <label></label>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="stop">
            <label></label>
        </f:facet>
</a4j:status>
<ui:include src="/modalPanel.xhtml" />
```

modalPanel.xhtml can contain display related content.

you can put the content above in a separate file say status.xhtml and then include it in your other pages
as below:

```
<a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
<ui:include src="status.xhtml" />
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

so any page that has ajax request will display above message window
You need not add any status msg for each a4j:button ,etc.