# Rich Faces rich:dataTable , how to stop row click before filtration of records complete

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am using the rich:dataTable and the problem is that when user enters some character to filter the record but before the filtration is completed the user clicks on a row and this is causing the problem.
Is there a way through which i can stop the user from clicking on a row before the filtration get completed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a4j:status with modal popup. See links with code:
[Call rich:modalPanel for every ajax request with out using a4j:status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108529/call-richmodalpanel-for-every-ajax-request-with-out-using-a4jstatus)

[Show loading status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122602/show-loading-status)